# AppArmor deny all except one path

Tags: docker, apparmor

In AppArmor for docker on Ubuntu, I have a directory /var/www that contains a bunch of virtual hosts' files. I want to deny all paths except one, so that each virtual host only sees their own files. I've tried so many things like:

```
deny /var/www/{**^,vhost1}/ rw,
```

Notice that I have a comma after **^ - I think this is because the {**^} syntax is not actually supported yet.  Does anyone know when that will be supported or how to get around this problem?

Judging from:

http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/QuickProfileLanguage

It still seems to be a "proposed feature".

> uname -a
>   Linux testerserver 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

`deny /var/www/[^vhost1]* rw,`

found the answer on https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#examples-using-globbing-to-match-files